# Negative lookahead in R to match delimited chunks in a string that do not contain an specific character

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I am trying to extract (from a string) all the chunks of characters between two `\r\n` expressions that do not contain a white space. To do so, I am using the negative lookahead operator.

This is my string:

```
my_string <- "\r\nContent: base64\r\n\r\nDBhHB\r\nDGlV\r\nPAAHJ\r\nAwQU\r\n"
```

And this is what I've tried:

```
pat <- "\\r\\n+(?! )\\r\\n.*"

out <- unlist(regmatches(my_string,
                         regexpr(pat, my_string, perl=TRUE)))
```

This is what I got in R:

```
> out
 [1] "\r\n\r\nDBhHB\r\n"
```

As you can see, it stops on the first match.

**EDIT**

My expected output, in this case, would be the final part of the string.

```
> out
 [1] "DBhHB\r\nDGlV\r\nPAAHJ\r\nAwQU\r\n"
```

I would like to be able to retrieve multiple parts if there is another one or two white spaces in other chunks in the middle of the string.

```
my_string <- "\r\nNot This\r\n\r\KeepThis\r\nKeepThis\r\nNot This\r\nKeepThis\r\n"
```

Suggestions under the base R approach would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For readability and testing, I'd strongly suggest shortening your example to make it more readable and clear, while also illustrating the complexity of "retrieve multiple parts if there is another one or two white spaces in other chunks in the middle of the string". If the input were `my_string <- "\r\nBad Has Spaces\r\n\r\nKeepThis\r\nKeepThisToo\r\nNot This\r\nChunk2a\r\nChunk2b"`, what would your expected output be?

Comment: As for working for the solution, look-ahead is used when you want to check something *after* the match. But you want no spaces in the match, not no spaces after the match. I would suggest trying `pat = "\\r\\n[^ ]+\\r\\n". The greedy nature of matching should get you maximal matches in that case.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor Thomas. I've edited the text. With regard to your other suggestion, it did work for the first example, but not when there is more than one white space in other chunks. I will try to work on it and see what I get. Thanks again

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/hlrbQJ/1? Or, `(?m)^\S+(?:\R\S+)*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hlrbQJ/2))?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting it, @Wiktor Stribizeźew. Yes, it did. Thank you! Would you mind posting an alternative solution using base R? I’ve tried to replicate it with regexpr() but without success.

Comment: @allanvc How annoying, the PCRE library was not compiled with `PCRE_BSR_ANYCRLF `  option. I updated the answer with the base R solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Didn’t know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
(?m)^\S+(?:\R\S+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hlrbQJ/3). Details:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `^` - this anchor now matches all line start positions
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\R\S+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a line break sequence and then one or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of a line.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/jBRzuw):

```
library(stringr)
my_string <- "\r\nContent: base64\r\n\r\nDBhHB\r\nDGlV\r\nPAAHJ\r\nAwQU\r\n"
pat <- "(?m)^\\S+(?:\\R\\S+)*$"
unlist(str_extract_all(my_string, pat))
## => [1] "DBhHB\r\nDGlV\r\nPAAHJ\r\nAwQU"

my_string <- "\r\nNot This\r\n\r\nKeepThis\r\nKeepThis\r\nNot This\r\nKeepThis\r\n"
unlist(str_extract_all(my_string, pat))
## => [1] "KeepThis\r\nKeepThis" "KeepThis"
```

**Base R usage**

Note that in base R, PCRE engine is used, and `$` in a multiline mode (when `(?m)` is used) *only matches right before `\n`*. Since you have `\r\n` line endings, you cannot use plain `$` to mark the line end. Consuming `\r` is not a good idea (`\r$`) as you do not want to have `\r` in the output. **You can tell PCRE to treat CRLF, CR or LF as line ending sequence with the `(*ANYCRLF)` PCRE verb**:

```
unlist(regmatches(my_string, gregexpr("(*ANYCRLF)(?m)^\\S+(?:\\R\\S+)*$",my_string, perl=TRUE)))
```

Note `(*ANYCRLF)` PCRE verb must be at the start of the regex pattern.

See [this R demo online](https://ideone.com/9UJe66).